# React routing issue with hashHistory push

Tags: reactjs, react-router, hashtag

i define a react routing path like this:

```
/customer/:cid
```

When i navigate to the desired path calling hash history push from my saga like this:

```
yield call(hashHistory.push, `/customer/${cid}`);
```

I dont see the 'customer' word in the browser and also a warning is appearing that the url did not match a routing path. When i use `/${cid}` expect from `/customer/${cid}` the router is working fine. What am i missing?

Comment: What's the point of using yield call here, the function is synchronous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could try:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, `#/customer/${cid}`);
```

Or make a module hashHistory:

```
// hashHistory.js
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
export default createHashHistory({});
```

And use it:

```
import hashHistory from './hashHistory';
// ....
hashHistory.push(`/customer/${cid}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can skip the first forward slash that is prefixed to **customer**.
Because url that your are pushing to hashHistory is relative to app root url. So just skip the first forward slash. Hope that helps